# Firebase authentication with Microsoft error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to implement Firebase Authentication on my Android app for my organization. Every employee has a Microsoft business account so I want to use that email/password to sign in on my app.

I enabled this option on the Firebase Console and filled data with the information of the Azure AD application I created:

[image]

The Azure AD app has the permission to log in users and read their profile.

[image]

I managed to get it working to the point where the users are created on my Firebase Console.

[image]

But on my Android app, after writing the credentials, this error message appears.

> We're having trouble signing you in.
>   AADSTS900561: The endpoint only accepts POST requests. Received a GET request.

[image]

The Android code is the sample code Firebase gives.

```
OAuthProvider.Builder provider = OAuthProvider.newBuilder("microsoft.com");

Task < AuthResult > pendingResultTask = mAuth.getPendingAuthResult();
if (pendingResultTask != null) {
    pendingResultTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < AuthResult >
        () {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                Log.e("PROFILE", authResult.getAdditionalUserInfo()
                    .getProfile().toString());
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e("FAIL", "ERROR LOGIN");
        }
    });
} else {
    mAuth.startActivityForSignInWithProvider(Login.this, provider.build())
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < AuthResult > () {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                Log.e("PROFILE", authResult.getAdditionalUserInfo()
                    .getProfile().toString());
                Log.w("USERNAME", authResult.getUser()
                    .getDisplayName());

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e("FAIL", "ERROR LOGIN: " + e);
            }
        });
}
```

The `PROFILE` logline is being printed and there are no errors in Android Studio. Also if the user is being created on Firebase...I don't know what's causing the login process not to be completed.

**EDIT:**
This is my redirect URI configuration on Azure AD app:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
The supported account type is set to all accounts. (It's in Spanish sorry, it says I can edit the manifest to change the configuration)

[image]

The manifest looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "******************************",
  "acceptMappedClaims": null,
  "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
  "allowPublicClient": null,
  "appId": "***************************",
  "appRoles": [],
  "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
  "createdDateTime": "2019-04-02T09:53:53Z",
  "groupMembershipClaims": null,
  "identifierUris": ["api://****************************"],
  "informationalUrls": {
    "termsOfService": null,
    "support": null,
    "privacy": null,
    "marketing": null
  },
  "keyCredentials": [],
  "knownClientApplications": [],
  "logoUrl": null,
  "logoutUrl": null,
  "name": "App name",
  "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
  "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
  "oauth2Permissions": [],
  "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
  "optionalClaims": null,
  "orgRestrictions": [],
  "parentalControlSettings": {
    "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
    "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
  },
  "passwordCredentials": [
    {
      "customKeyIdentifier": null,
      "endDate": "2099-12-31T12:00:00Z",
      "keyId": "***************************",
      "startDate": "2019-04-02T09:55:10.2084897Z",
      "value": null,
      "createdOn": "2019-04-02T09:55:14.432352Z",
      "hint": "gGL",
      "displayName": null
    }
  ],
  "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
  "publisherDomain": "domain.com",
  "replyUrlsWithType": [
    {
      "url": "https://***********.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler",
      "type": "Web"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf",
      "type": "InstalledClient"
    },
    {
      "url": "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
      "type": "InstalledClient"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient",
      "type": "InstalledClient"
    },
    {
      "url": "msalececeef1-*****************://auth",
      "type": "InstalledClient"
    }
  ],
  "requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
      "resourceAppId": "*************************",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "***********************",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "samlMetadataUrl": null,
  "signInUrl": null,
  "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
  "tags": [],
  "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

I've tried changing the `"oauth2RequirePostResponse": false` to `true` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Have you configured things as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/microsoft-oauth?authuser=0?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I did. I added an extra image to show the Azure URI redirection, but you can see I followed that site religiously on the rest of the images and code. I'm thinking maybe a permission is missing since that part isn't really explained.

Comment: It looks like this is meant to work with the v2 Endpoint. Make sure the "Supported Account Types" section of the Authentication blade is _not_ set to **"Accounts in this organizational directory only (Microsoft)"** or **"Accounts in any organizational directory"**. The **"Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox, Outlook.com)"** is for the v2 Endpoint.

Comment: Check my edit. The correct option was enabled but mayne there is something on the manifest that can help? thank you for your time.

Comment: did you resolve this? I am struggling as well. It seems their documentation is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to check the token check-boxes under Manage -> Authentication?
For me that was the difference